# On cohomology of divisors on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface (over complex numbers). Let $D$ be a non-zero effective divisor on $X$. Let us also assume that we don't know apriori whether $D$ is ample or not. I'm trying to understand the meaning of $h^1(\mathcal O_X(mD))=0$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$ (or atleast after a big enough threshold). Here $mD:=D+D+D+...D(m \text{times})$

Is this condition natural to expect? or is this too strong and thus rarely happens? and is  a polynomial estimate of $h^1(\mathcal O_X(mD))$ known in terms of how fast it grows as m becomes bigger and bigger?

Is there any chance that if $h^1(\mathcal O_X(nD))=0$ for some $n$, then $h^1(\mathcal O_X(mD))=0$ for all $m \geq n$?

Does there exist any equivalent interpretation of this condition ( I mean using some standard exact sequence)?

Finally, does there exist an explicit construction of such a pait $(X,D)$?

Any remark from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This will hold if $D$ is ample, and $h^2$ will eventually vanish as well; this is part of the content of the Serre vanishing theorem. There are various other conditions that one can look for, but higher cohomology vanishing is, in a certain sense, one of the central problems of algebraic geometry.

The natural way to understand sheaf cohomology is as an obstruction. The goal is pretty much always using (some variation on) the fact that if a line bundle/divisor has vanishing higher cohomology, then $\chi(D) = h^0(D) - h^1(D) + h^2(D) = h^0(D)$, and $\chi(D)$ can generally be computed effectively from standard exact sequences. Thus in such cases we can determine the dimension of the projective space that $D$ maps $X$ into.

For explicit constructions, it's not exactly clear what you mean. If you just want some example, $\mathbb P^2$ and a line therein does the job.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can we say anything particular when we know nothing about whether $D$ is ample or not?

Comment: I understand that if $D$ is ample, then this first cohomology vanishing condition is satisfied after a threshold. Are you saying that ample and this first cohomology vanishing condition are equivalent? If not then is there an example of proper containment?

Comment: No, ampleness is equivalent to asymptotic vanishing of $h^1$ *and* $h^2$ for $\mathcal F\otimes \mathcal O_X(mD)$, where $\mathcal F$ is an arbitrary coherent sheaf (and the minimal $m$ may vary with $\mathcal F$). This is, as I said, the content of Serre's vanishing theorem specialized to the case $\dim X = 2$. I do not know an example of proper containment, and indeed for all I know one may need to work in higher dimensions to find such a thing.